# По неведомым мне причинам не отправляется сообщение пользователю

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api, callback

```
from flask import Flask, request, json
#тут лежит токен и токен проверки
from settings import *
import vk
from random import random

app = Flask(__name__)
#Проверка перезагрузки сайта
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hi there'


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def processing():
    #Распаковываем json из пришедшего POST-запроса
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    #Узнаём какой запрос мы получили от ВК
    if 'type' not in data.keys():
        return 'not vk'
    #Если подтверждение сервера (проходит успешно)
    if data['type'] == 'confirmation':
        return confirmation_token
    #Если новое сообщение
    elif data['type'] == 'message_new':
        random_id = round(random() * 10 ** 9)
        session = vk.Session()
        api = vk.API(session, v=5.103)
        user_id = data['object']['message']['from_id']
        api.messages.send(message="Привет, username!", peer_id = int(user_id), access_token=token, v=5.103, random_id=random_id )
        # Сообщение о том, что обработка прошла успешно
        return 'ok'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Я хотел бы понять по какой причине я не получаю сообщения от бота

Answer (score 0):

В итоге код оказался рабочим проблема была в плохо работающем хостинге. -5часов жизни